# Autorization using Get and value

Tags: asp.net

I want to authenticate a request - passing it the - and then it stranivaya on the server if the same - that avtorihovalsya - if not, then there is no

What can be done iskusttveno - without using controls (using the classes as well):
  Translate user from nezaregestirovannogo in zaregestirovannogo:

For example:

I make a request http://Login.aspx?Hash=jiojor

Check in Page_Load if the database user with the Hash = jiojor

If yes, then:

Register.User (nameUser) = true
  And the user is logged in nameUser

Comment: This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: Please read [Is English required on StackOverflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/143130)?

Comment: Sorry, I used Translator

Comment: I send in a method get of url value
Like: url?Value="My Value"

In C# code I compare "My Value" and value from data base 
if they are identical, then user is log in, else not log in
There is class, whicth can manually authorize user, like:

Authorize.User("My Value" or "Username") = true;